# having trouble compiling an array

Tags: arrays

When I try to compile the code below, I get an error message saying "missing number" and "illegal of measure" in reference to the specific part [\hskip.017in -1,\sin{a}\hskip.017in]. I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Please help. Thank you!

```
$$ f^{-1}\big((-\infty,a\hskip.017in]\big)\ =\ \left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
[\hskip.017in -1,1\hskip.017in] & {} & a>\frac{\pi}{2} \\
{} & {} & {} \\
[\hskip.017in -1,\sin{a}\hskip.017in] & {} & a\in\left[\hskip.017in -\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\hskip.017in \right] \\
{} & {} & {} \\
\varnothing & {} & a<-\frac{\pi}{2} \\
\end{array}\right.\ \in\ \mathcal{L} $$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `{}` right before `[\hskip.017in -1,\sin{a}\hskip.017in]`. Otherwise, LaTeX will think that you are trying to increase the space between lines using an expression which is not a length.

Besides, I have a suggestion for you: [use `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/134805).